# How to make as transparent glow while selecting action bar custom spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using action bar in my application. I created menu and custom navigation item for my action bar. When i click my menu and button in my action bar i can able to transparent my glow color. Like this.

**action_item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#D3D3D3"/> // This is my action bar color
```

**ab_item_background.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" >

<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/action_item_background" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

I added these lines in my style.xml.

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
```

But when i click my spinner these styles not applicable for that. It comes as blue color. I am not using Sherlock action bar. How can i do this? Can any body tell me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this issue. I use this link.

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/.

I selected the option what I need and generate style and download it. I copied all the file into my application with corresponding folders. I can achieve by this. I got an exact result.